# VSS Check In Whole Site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I am trying to work with Visual Source Safe while developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 site in Visual Studio Web Developer Express.  There doesn't seem to be any integration between VS and VSS so I have to check in and check out manually.

During the course of a day, I create and modify many files, and so it is annoying to have to do VSS checkin/ checkout every time.  Is there anyway to, instead, just check in the entire site at the end of the day?

That way, I will have a working copy of [Monday's] version of the site, and on Tuesday at the end of the day I would have a working version of Tuesday's version of the site.  Then, can these be deleted over time?

Comment: vss supports checking in a folder recursively, so check in the entire site at the end of the day is doable. If you are going with command line for auto checkin, Someone from [this post](http://forums.dynamsoft.com/recursive-checkin-in-command-line-t11086.html?sid=5807b017340f4f09530d88c5dd416b2c) has the same concern as you. "Then, can these be deleted over time?" You can archive histories. [How to: Archive a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0t9wzx(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The express edition of Visual Studio doesn't provide any integration with VSS. If you'd like to do the check-in/check-out directly in Visual Studio, I recommend you upgrade your VS.

Also, you can take advantage of the VSS command line. You can execute the command to check in the entire site at the end of the day, and perform check-out on the next day.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asxkfzy4(v=vs.80).aspx

Although the command line may simplify the process, I still recommend you check in the modifications in time.

Comment: Do you have any idea what a simple command would look like to checkout/checkin my entire site which is located in `C:\Users\darchual\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyBlog`?

Comment: You can use the Checkin and Checkout commands. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/003ssz4z(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks so it looks like I can use `ss Checkout -R $/MyBlog` to checkout then how do I check in?  It says I can check in the current directory with `ss Checkin * -P`, but how do I set the current directory?